# How to resolve conflict issues with jQuery + other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me figure out how to write a no conflict function for js for my weebly website.

http://cadogan.weebly.com/big-name.html

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a "no conflict function"?

Comment: I am using a jquery plugin on my website which is supposed to perform an innerzoom function on the images. This has stopped working I suspect it is a conflict with the webhost and the jquery. But I am not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean that you get errors when you try to reference jQuery using $.

Since you are loading Scriptaculous after jQuery, it is overwriting the $ alias to jQuery. You can instead us the jQuery object directly.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#mydiv').html("<h1>hi</h1>");
});
```

Comment: I am not getting an error message the function the script is supposed to do was partially working and now has stopped.

Comment: You might not get an error message. $ is still a valid object, it just contains Scriptaculous instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `jQuery` instead of `$`, or using the `.noConflict()` method:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/